# How to reset anything related to Ruby to factory settings on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos

After a number of misadventures involving RVM, Ruby and Rails on my new laptop have left me completely bewildered. I uninstalled RVM but all the paths, versions and permissions are all messed up.

I searched and couldn't find the right fixes. It feels like each solution makes the problem get worse.

I want to start fresh without having to reset my computer to factory settings. How can I reset just the Ruby-related things like Ruby, Rails, etc., without erasing my computer?

Comment: Reinstalling the OS seems like the obvious answer. Why don't you want to do that? Alternatively, assuming you have backup, restore it to the way it was right before you made the changes you want to undo. I don't see you have much choice.

Comment: I guess it didn't seem obvious to me, which is why I asked. But if there's no way to just reset ruby etc. then I suppose I have to. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: This isn't asked well. You're asking us to imagine every possible thing you could have done without telling us anything useful. Apple installs the system Ruby for their own use; It's ok to run scripts against it but modifying it can break processes Apple installed. Instead, ALWAYS use a sandbox manager like rbenv, RVM or asdf to install a separate, user-modifiable Ruby. And, don't ever use `sudo` until you know exactly what it does and what the command is going to do; `sudo` is like a surgeon's scalpel and capable of major damage in the wrong hands, especially when working with system files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would close & reopen your terminal window before you start all of this to make sure you don't have any old env vars loaded.

General things:

- Run `env | grep RUBY`, `env | grep RVM` and look for any leftover environment variables that you may have set
- Same for `env | grep GEM`. Sometimes you'll see `GEM_PATH`, `GEM_HOME`, etc. but these aren't necessary for system ruby
- Peek inside your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, and `~/.profile` files and see if you've added any rvm stuff

If you're running macOS Mojave (I'm comparing against my system):

`which ruby` should return `/usr/bin/ruby`. If it doesn't, you have something else interfering. Post what that is and we can get it fixed.

Running `/usr/bin/ruby --version` should return `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]`

Permissions for system ruby:

```
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  52016 Nov 30 02:38 /usr/bin/ruby
```

This should be something like `sudo chmod 555 /usr/bin/ruby` to fix this if yours is difference. If you have different owners you'll need to `sudo chown root:wheel /usr/bin/ruby`

You'll also want to check `which gem`, and see if it reports `/usr/bin/gem`. Permissions should be the same as `/usr/bin/ruby`. `/usr/bin/gem --version` should return `2.5.2.3`

Running `/usr/bin/gem env` should return something similar-ish to below. Replace `jay` (my computer user) with yours

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jay/.gem/ruby/2.3.0 # this doesn't matter much
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jay/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/jay/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => false
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/"]
     - "benchmark" => true
     - "gem" => "--document=yri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/jay/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

From there you've got two directories you probably want to look at:

Run `ls -al /Library/Ruby/`. You should see this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96 Aug 17 18:59 Gems
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96 Aug 17 18:59 Site
```

You may need to chmod/chown each of those directories (with `-R` for recursive)

When you're done, please note that running `/usr/bin/gem install bundler` and `gem install bundler` (assuming you haven't installed a new ruby version manager) should yield an error as below (this means you re-configured the permissions correctly).

```
Fetching: bundler-1.17.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

You'll see some tutorials mention changing those permissions, or running sudo to install gems but I don't recommend that. My favorite ruby version manager is [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) which may be worth a look. You'll install the core, and the [ruby plugin](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby).

This should get you a little bit closer. If you see anything else messed up, please post the error.

Comment: macOS Catalina has very different permission limitations so I suspect this won't work.

Comment: The OP specified macOS High Sierra in the original question. I haven't had to do this on macOS Catalina yet but you're right, the steps (and paths) are likely not exactly the same (but should be similar)

Comment: Catalina has had major changes to protect the system files. I won't even mess around with it anymore; It's not worth the effort when we have so many other ways of adding our development systems now.

Answer (score -1):

`rm -rf ~/.rvm`, then edit `~/.bash_profile` to remove `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`.

Then you can restart with RVM from scratch by following the detailed installation instructions at https://rvm.io/rvm/install.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I've already uninstalled RVM. That's not my problem—I'd like to completely reset ruby and everything related to it to the way it would be "out of the box." RVM is long gone, but a bunch of other subtle things are out of whack.

Comment: What @anothermh suggested will work fine. What "subtle" things concern you?

Comment: I already did those things, I'm not sure how they help when RVM was already uninstalled that way. I've encountered a circle of problems and errors with paths, permission, bundler, etc. I spent several hours reading overflow threads and trying things in terminal, and I'm confident that there isn't a simple solution. That's why I was hoping for help with the above question.

Comment: @Forrest Then perhaps you should explain your problem better, because your question says you were having trouble with RVM, Ruby, and Rails, and since RVM does not write outside of ~/.rvm, the ONLY thing you need to do is delete it. If you’re having a problem with **system Ruby** then **be specific**. _messed up_ is **not specific**.

Comment: I explained that I had already uninstalled RVM and that I wanted to know how to remove Ruby and any related software from my system in order to reinstall it with default settings. I didn't say that RVM was the sole cause of my problems. That was very clear, but I hadn't anticipated the extent to which people would think I was mistaken and want me to have asked different questions. Apologies.

Comment: The level of detail in your question led me to believe that you probably did not know how to properly remove RVM, since you said you removed it but were still having trouble with Ruby and Rails (which is a series of gems, again indicating no expertise with the matter). On Stackoverflow you need to **be specific** about the problems you're having. The words _messed up_, _misadventures_, _out of whack_, _bewildered_ are **totally meaningless**. Saying _the problem gets worse_ but then not describing the problem means no one can help you until you help yourself.

Comment: I was *specific*—I asked this question: "I want to start fresh without having to reset my computer to factory settings. How can I reset just the ruby-related things (ruby, rails, etc.) without erasing my computer?" What I got was condescension, antagonism, and some pretty obvious confusion about the nature of language's relationship to meaning.

Comment: At this point, all I can recommend is that you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I have been trying to help you for hours now. I'm not sure there's anything more I can do to help if you're unwilling to provide useful information about the problem.

Comment: which ruby returns /Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/shims/ruby which I'm not sure how to reset/fix. Any ideas?